# Error in LSTM-based RNN training: "IndexError: index out of range" during DataLoader iteration

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

I'm currently working on training an LSTM-based RNN using PyTorch and encountering an error during the training loop I've tried various solutions to resolve this issue but I'm still facing the same error message. Here's the relevant code snippet

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
import pandas as pd
import json

class RNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim):
        super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
        # Define your layers here
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        embedded = self.embedding(x)
        output, (h_n, c_n) = self.rnn(embedded)
        return self.fc(output)

# Load tokenized vocabulary
with open('cleaned_vocab.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as vocab_file:
    vocab = json.load(vocab_file)

# Load processed data from CSV
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_path, max_seq_length):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        self.max_seq_length = max_seq_length
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.data.loc[idx, 'text']
        tokens = [int(token) for token in text.split()]
        
        if len(tokens) > self.max_seq_length:
            tokens = tokens[:self.max_seq_length]
        
        padded_sequence = tokens + [0] * (self.max_seq_length - len(tokens))
        input_sequence = torch.tensor(padded_sequence[:-1])  # Input sequence without last token
        target_sequence = torch.tensor(padded_sequence[1:])   # Target sequence without first token
        return input_sequence, target_sequence

# Custom collate function
class CustomCollate:
    def __init__(self, pad_idx):
        self.pad_idx = pad_idx
    
    def __call__(self, batch):
        input_seqs, target_seqs = zip(*batch)
        padded_input_seqs = pad_sequence(input_seqs, batch_first=True, padding_value=self.pad_idx)
        padded_target_seqs = pad_sequence(target_seqs, batch_first=True, padding_value=self.pad_idx)
        return padded_input_seqs, padded_target_seqs

# Initialize custom dataset
max_sequence_length = 30  # Define your desired maximum sequence length
dataset = CustomDataset('processed_data.csv', max_sequence_length)

# Create a dataloader with custom collate function
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, collate_fn=CustomCollate(0))

# Initialize the RNN model
vocab_size = len(vocab)
embedding_dim = 128
hidden_dim = 256
rnn_model = RNNModel(vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim)

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(rnn_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for input_batch, target_batch in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        output = rnn_model(input_batch)

        # Calculate loss and backpropagate
        loss = criterion(output.transpose(1, 2), target_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

# Save the trained model
torch.save(rnn_model.state_dict(), 'rnn_model.pth')

print("Training completed.")
```

I've verified my csv file adjusted the 'max_seq_length' parameter to ensure it is appropriate for my data Double-checked the data pre-processing steps, including padding and formatting

Any suggestions on how to further debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the full error.

Comment: @overmach thats all the error says it just says the lines with it 
output = rnn_model(input_batch) and
embedded = self.embedding(x)